# Pyrogram RuntimeError

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I am trying to create echo telebot, this is my code:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client('my_account')

@app.on_message(filters.me)
def echo(client, message):
    message.reply_text(message.text)

app.run()
```

After I run this code, I logged in Telegram, but after logging in, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 437, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
RuntimeError: <_overlapped.Overlapped object at 0x0000022E1F8CB420> still has pending operation at deallocation, the process may crash
```

And when I always run this code, I get this error. Please help me.